# Unable to list Sentinel l1c file using AWS CLI

Tags: python, gdal, geotiff-tiff, sentinel-2, amazon-web-services

Following Setting for AWS CLI using AWS configure

> AWS Access Key ID : **********
> AWS Secret Access Key : ********
> Default region name : eu-central-1

which I get from IAM user

After setup I try to run following commands

```
aws s3 ls s3://sentinel-s2-l1c/ --request-payer requester
```

getting error as

> An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the ListObjects operation: Access Denied

when I try to run

```
 aws s3 ls --request-payer requester s3://sentinel-s2-l1c/
```

getting same error

And when I try to copy the folder I get

```
aws s3 cp --request-payer requester s3://sentinel-s2-l1c/tiles/43/R/EQ/2017/7/productInfo.json pi.json
```

Error like this

> Unknown options: --request-payer,pi.json

When I try to use `wget`

```
wget -O test.tar.gz "http://sentinel-s2-l1c.s3-website.eu-central-1.amazonaws.com/tiles/43/R/EQ/2017/7/7/0/B01.jp2?AWSAccessKeyId=********&Signature=**********"
```

I get error 403

How can I do this?

Comment: Have "AmazonS3FullAccess" and "AmazonEC2FullAccess" policy attach to your IAM user. Preferably create new role and attach these policies to resolve the issue